# Mathematical vs. Computer Science Definition Big $O$

Tags: asymptotics, definition, computer-science

In some formal mathematical treatments of asymptotic big $O$ notation, it's usually defined something like this:

Definition (Asymptotic Big $O$ notation): Let $X\subseteq\textbf R$ be a subset of the real line $\textbf R$, and let $f,g:X\to\textbf R$ be real-valued functions. Then $f$ is said to be asymptotically big $O$ of $g$ (and we write $f\in O(g)$, or sometimes $f=O(g)$) iff there exists a positive real number $c>0$ and a real number $M\in\textbf R$ such that for all $x\in X\cap[M,+\infty)$, we have that $|f(x)|\leq c|g(x)|$.

My question is how exactly does this relate to the more informal notion of big $O$ used in computer science, and specifically in the analysis of the run-time of algorithms? Take the binary search algorithm for instance, which people often just say runs in $O(\log(n))$ time...but here, what is the function $f(n)$ in this situation?

Comment: $f$ is the actual running time of the algorithm, $\log n$ is the asymptotic bound

Comment: The function is $f(n) = $ the greatest number of steps the algorithm can take on an input of size $n$. It's usually written as $T(n)$ where $T$ stands for "time". Thus, if $f(n) = O(\log n)$, then the algorithm is said to "run in $\log n$ time in the worst case".

Comment: $f$ is the function that maps the problem size to the running time for a problem of that size.

Comment: In CS is used exactly same formal definition usually for non negative functions defined on $\mathbb{N}$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Given a positive integer $n\in\textbf Z^+$, consider the list
$$1,2,3,...,n$$
comprised of the first $n$ positive integers. You have to guess some positive integer $1\leq x\leq n$ contained somewhere in this list, and whenever you make a guess, you are told one of three things
$$1.\text{Your guess is too high :(}$$
$$2.\text{Your guess is too low :(}$$
$$3.\text{Your guess is correct!}$$
How can you guess what $x$ is? Let me go over two possible strategies. The first one is called *linear search*. Basically, what you do is guess that $x=1$, and if you get it correct then you celebrate and go drink a lot of beer, while if you are told that $1$ is too low, then you guess the next number in the list, i.e. you guess $x=2$, and if this is correct then you celebrate and go drink a lot of beer, while if you are told that $2$ is too low, then you guess the next number $3$, and this process keeps repeating until you guess the correct number (and go celebrate and drink a lot of beer). For each positive integer $n\in\textbf Z^+$, I'm going to let $T_{\text{linear}}(n)$ denote the **maximum** number of guesses that you need to correctly guess what $x$ is in a list of length $n$ using the linear search algorithm described above. Convince yourself then that the following table of values is indeed accurate:
\begin{array}{r|c}
n & T_{\text{linear}}(n) \\
\hline
1 & 1 \\
2 & 2 \\
3 & 3 \\
4 & 4 \\
5 & 5 \\
6 & 6 \\
7 & 7 \\
8 & 8 \\
9 & 9 \\
\vdots & \vdots
\end{array}
In short, for all positive integers $n\in\textbf Z^+$, $T_{\text{linear}}(n)=n$.

Now let's consider another strategy called *binary search*. Here, you start by guessing that $x$ is the "middle term" in the list, say $x=n/2$ if $n$ is even and $x=\frac{n+1}{2}$ is $n$ is odd. If the guess is correct, then you're done, while if the guess is too low then you have basically eliminated $\approx 1/2$ of the possibilities for what $x$ could be, and then you just apply the whole procedure again to the remaining half of the list, and you keep doing this until you guess correctly. For each possible list length $n\in\textbf Z^+$, let $T_{\text{binary}}(n)$ denote the **maximum** number of guesses that you need to correctly guess what $x$ is in a list of length $n$ using the binary search algorithm described above. In this case, convince yourself that the following table of values is correct:

\begin{array}{r|c}
n & T_{\text{binary}}(n) \\
\hline
1 & 1 \\
2 & 2 \\
3 & 2 \\
4 & 3 \\
5 & 3 \\
6 & 3 \\
7 & 3 \\
8 & 4 \\
9 & 4 \\
\vdots & \vdots
\end{array}

and that in general, for all positive integers $n\in\textbf Z^+$, we have that $T_{\text{binary}}(n)=\lfloor\log_2(n)\rfloor+1$. Below in red is the graph of the $T_{\text{linear}}$ function while in green is the graph of the $T_{\text{binary}}$ function:[image]

Overall, it is clear that binary search is a much more *efficient* algorithm than linear search when it comes to this particular task of guessing a number in a list, especially as the list gets larger and larger (i.e. as $n\to\infty$). Computer scientists will often say that linear search runs in at worst $O(n)$ time (or *linear time*), while binary search runs in at worst $O(\log(n))$ time (or *logarithmic time*). This is because, using the notation from the original post, we have $X=\textbf Z^+$, $f(n)=T_{\text{linear}}(n)=n$ or $f(n)=T_{\text{binary}}(n)=\lfloor\log_2(n)\rfloor+1$, and $g(n)=n$ or $g(n)=\log(n)$ respectively, since in the first case we can choose $c:=1$ and $M:=1$ for instance, while in the latter case we can choose $c:=5$ and $M:=4$.

Answer (score 1):

**Big O-notation:** There is *no difference* between the usage of the *Big O*-notation in mathematics and computer science. Both areas use precisely the same definition.

Let's have a look for instance at section 1.2.11.1: *The $O$-notation* in *[The Art of Computer Programming, Vol. 1](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Art_of_Computer_Programming)* by Don Knuth:

> - *TAOCP 1 (1.2.11.1):* A very convenient notation for dealing with approximations was introduced by P. Bachmann in the book *Analytische Zahlentheorie* in 1892. This is the *big-oh* notation which allows us to replace the $\approx$ sign by $=$; for example
>   \begin{align*}
>   H_n=\ln n+\gamma +O\left(\frac{1}{n}\right)
>   \end{align*}
>   ...
>   Every appearance of $O(f(n))$ means precisely this: there is a positive constant $M$ such that the number $x_n$ represented by $O(f(n))$ satisfies the condition $|x_n|\leq M|f(n)|$, for all $n\geq n_0$. We do not say *what* the constants $M$ and $n_0$ are, and indeed these constants are usually different for each appearance of $O$.

This is precisely the definition which is used in mathematics (asymptotic analysis). Somewhat later this definition introduced for sequences is extended to real-valued functions and a fundamental aspect of the big-O notation is emphasized in:

> The most important consideration is the idea of *one-way equalities*: We write $\frac{1}{2}n^2+n=O\left(n^2\right)$, but we *never* write $O\left(n^2\right)=\frac{1}{2}n^2+n$ ...We always use the convention that *the right-hand side of an equation does not give more information than the left-hand side*; the right-hand side is a *crudification* of the left.
>
> This convention about the use of $=$ may be stated more precisely as follows: Formulas which involve the $O(f(n))$-notation may be regarded as sets of functions of $n$. The symbol $O(f(n))$ stands for the set of all functions $g$ such that there exists a constant $M$ with $|g(n)|\leq M|f(n)|$ for all large $n$.

Here we see again how the big-O notation is used.

**Binary search:** Skimming through volume III of TAOCP we find in section 6.2.1 a subsection titled *Further analysis of binary search*. We see that the run-time is here measured in units of comparisons of memory-cells. Different algorithms are presented and analysed. The analysis is summarised in

> - *TAOCP 3 (6.2.1):* To summarize: Algorithm B never makes more than $\lfloor \lg N\rfloor + 1$ comparisons, and it makes about $\lg N-1$  comparisons in an average successful search. No search method based on comparisons can do better than this. The average running time of Program B is approximately
>   \begin{align*}
>   &(18 \lg N -16)u\qquad \text{for a successful search}\\
>   &(18 \lg N + 12)u\qquad \text{for an unseccessful search}
>   \end{align*}

Here we see *typical examples* of the statement *a binary search* has a run-time $O(\log n)$. We have
\begin{align*}
\color{blue}{(18 \lg N -16)u}&\color{blue}{=O(\log n)}\\
\color{blue}{(18 \lg N + 12)u}&\color{blue}{=O(\log n)}\
\end{align*}
Where $u$ is considered to be a constant, and $\lg N$ is the *binary logarithm* with $\lg N=\frac{\log N}{\log 2}$.